# Angular7 in production mode: Uncaught ReferenceError: environment is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

My application works fine in development, and `ng build --prod --source-map` builds application successfully. But when I try to access it in the browser, I get this error:

```
app.module.ts:47 Uncaught ReferenceError: env is not defined
    at Object.zUnb (app.module.ts:47)
    at u (bootstrap:81)
```

Here is my `app.module.ts` file (relevant part):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment as env } from '@env/environment'; // <- import env
import { CoreModule } from '@app/core/core.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    CoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: env.baseHref } // <--- error
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And this is my `tsconfig.json` file where @env path is defined:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I upgraded `@angular-devkit/build-angular` from version `~0.6.0` to `^0.13.3` and it solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
import { environment } as env from '@env/environment';
```

this should do the trick...

Comment: complier complains about this: `TS1005: ';' expected. TS2304: Cannot find name 'from'`

Comment: try `import * as env from '@env/environment';` ?

Comment: TS2339: Property 'baseHref' does not exist on type 'typeof import("path-to-project/src/environments/environment")'.